# How do I solve the error:cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (3,3,1)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have created this sample code where img1 and img2 are my image vectors converted into grayscale values. The val1,val2 variables are the outputs for the images. I need to use X in order to format the input features to train a neural net, But, when I use the reshape dunction it throws this error. how do I solve that?
Here is my Code:

```
check = []
img1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
val1=[0,1]
img2=[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
val2=[1,0]
check.append([np.array(img1),np.array(val1)])
check.append([np.array(img2),np.array(val2)])
print(check)

X = np.array(i[0] for i in check).reshape(-1,3,3,1)
print(X)
```

Comment: `X = np.array([i[0] for i in check]).reshape(-1,3,3,1)`

Comment: I suppose the error told you the shape of the sources was (1,), but did you then look further into the nature of that size 1 array?  For example, `dtype`, and what was that single element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line `X = np.array(i[0] for i in check).reshape(-1,3,3,1)` the thing that I think you meant to be a list comprehension lacks the enclosing [...] to make it so.  Without those brackets, the i[0]...check is interpreted as a generator comprehension (gives a generator not an iterator) and so just generates the 1st element (which creates an array of size 1 - hence the error).

```
X = np.array(list(i[0] for i in check)).reshape(-1,3,3,1)
```

OR

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in check]).reshape(-1,3,3,1)
```

will fix the issue.

Comment: What you call a "tuple comprehension" is more correctly called a "generator expression".